# amazon opsowrks custom monit configuration file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, chef-recipe, aws-opsworks

I have spent couple of hours trying to change default monit config .monitrc file in amazon opsworks. What I did is read all the recipes and find out the template in which this config is created: https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/blob/fb21127bf1e79e91ccbeaa47907774898bc237c5/deploy/specs/nodejs_spec.rb

```
monit_config = file(::File.join(node[:monit][:conf_dir], "node_web_app-#{app}.monitrc")
```

I tried to change conf_dir variable by passing Custom Chef JSON at deploy but with no luck.

```
{
   "monit": { "conf_dir": "/etc/monit/conf.d/custom" }
}
```

Could anybody help me. I dont want to rewrite recipes just to change monit config path if that is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using their NodeJS cookbooks, the monitrc is written out [inside the `opsworks_nodejs` definition](https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/blob/dbca69153bf9157bfca5034e957cdb75e67bd396/deploy/definitions/opsworks_nodejs.rb#L24-L36). It does not appear to be configurable. You can either use something like `chef-rewind` to hack it in, or write your own recipes instead.